# Azure Function Failed to disable function

Tags: azure-functions, azureportal

I have some functions running in a Linux hosted Function App on a Consumption Plan. When I try to disable them through the Azure Portal some fail with an error `[object Object]`.

[image]

Looking at the raw response in the browser dev tools indicates the error message is:

```
AppSetting with name 'AzureWebJobs.document-types.Disabled' is not allowed.
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After debugging for a while it seems many of the other functions can be disabled without issue. In the end I discovered that renaming the function solves the problem. It appears that the portal does not like names containing dashes `-`. After renaming the function to `documentTypes` I'm able to disable it without errors.

Comment: This is because Linux based functions are not allowed to have a dash in the name of the config so the naming convention of  AzureWebJobs.[FunctionNameWithDash].Disabled is not allowed.

Comment: That is what I eventually concluded. But it seems happy to accept my function names when I deploy them and does not list anything in logs which made the problem very hard to debug. I ended up simply guessing at solutions and stumbled upon the answer by accident.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a very similar (same?) error; turns out I needed to go to the `Function App` and `Stop` the whole app before disabling or deleting the `Function`.

Perhaps this happens because it was the the only function in the app, and I don't have deployment slots set up properly yet so it was in 'Production'.

Answer (score 0):

Please add a property in the function app configuration section
`AzureWebJobs.[functionAppName].Disabled` as `true`